# не работают консольные команды which python

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Захожу в консоль набираю which python

И консоль выдает это:

"which" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: @becouse windows 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что which это команда Linux.

В Windows вы можете использовать ее аналог where

> Команда WHERE используется для определения расположения файлов в
>   каталогах операционных систем Windows 7 и старше, имена которых
>   соответствуют задаваемому шаблону поиска, а также, при необходимости -
>   размера, даты и времени их изменения. По умолчанию поиск выполняется в
>   текущем каталоге и в каталогах, определяемых значением переменной
>   среды PATH.

Формат командной строки:

```
WHERE [/R каталог] [/Q] [/F] [/T] шаблон...
```

Например `where python`